# Why is UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape a macro?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm going through the [iOS Apprentice series](http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-apprentice).  The first tutorial introduces `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape`, and I noticed that its usage syntax looked like C, not Objective-C.  I looked it up, and learned that it is, as far as I can tell, what is known as a macro.  What is the rationale for using that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the overhead of calling a function.

Comment: If that were the case, why wouldn't as many functions as possible be macros?

Comment: The reason I create macros instead of functions is for speed. Things that will be called a lot, especially from loops. When the size of an operation grows beyond a few dozen machine instructions then the function overhead becomes negligible.